# Osmdroid blocking to load tile manually when zoom

Tags: android, android-maps, osmdroid

I have an issue with osmdroid.I got 11,12 and 13 zoom level tiles on Rome by Mobile Atlas Creator.Unzipped the atlas zip and I have changed the pngs manually.But of course, as you guess,I cant catch the correct scale ratio between zoom levels.I mean,if I place a marker on level 11,then I zoom to 12 , marker place is very different on second pngs tiles.I know the geoPoint is the same but my pngs locations change a little bit.

I realized that , when I zoom to level 14 , app just zoom to image without tile loading, because there is no tile for level 14 in my sdcard.And result is marker place doesnt change.
But as you guess,some tiles are blank because app try to load tiles for 14.So I think that if I prepare high defninition image and I use this image for all level 11,12 and 13,scale ratios will not change.But I must stop load tiles when zoom.Please correct me if I am on wrong way.How can I do that ?

Or how can I draw my own tiles for different level keeping ratio,easily ? Thanks for advices..

Comment: why you don't use the online map ?